# $_POST is not working in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

In Codeigniter, `$_GET['data']` is working properly where `$_POST['data']` and `$_REQUEST['data']` are not working.

Any One Knows the solution?

Code :

```
 public function index()
 {  
   echo $_POST['data'];
   exit;
 }
```

Comment: How are you sending the data? Share the form.

Comment: I am uses this in webservice api.

Comment: how are you calling the web service? We need that to help.

Comment: ok i am just calling the url : "http://impexdemo.com/d/scp/webservice/test/"

Comment: Wen you call the URL it sends a GET request. That's why you are getting the desired behaviour.

Comment: but i am using the google chrome postman app and i am passing the parameter as POST.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: sure i can share screenshot

Comment: i cant share screenshot on comment

Comment: upload it to imgur and share the link.

Comment: http://impexdemo.com/d/screenshot/2015-09-22_164303.png

Comment: if you change the echo to output "hello world" or some simple string, does it do that?  if not then your routing may be incorrect

Comment: ys i have also tried this one hello world its working but it only the POST data not printing. that why my all api is stopped.

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot I can see that you are actually sending the GET request to the URL. Because the url says

```
http://impexdemo.com/d/scp/webservice/test/?data=test
```

here `data=test` is a GET parameter. You have to set the `POST` parameter in the `request body` section in the postman.

Comment: yes you are right but in postman this is specified by this and there is also in left side post is selected.

Comment: suppose lets think i am passing the wrong parameter but the $_request must be working.

Comment: do a print_r($_REQUEST) and check the result.

Comment: same result data value is not comming

Answer (score 0):

In controller

```
 public function index()
 {
    $this->load->view("form");
 }

 public function add()
 {
    $data = $_POST['data']
    echo $data;
 }
```

And make sure your view form action is `"<?php echo base_url() ?>controller_name/method"` and there is input fild with `name='data'`

Your error comes is with **`exit()`** function. So remove it. Its work fine

Answer (score 0):

Thank You for help.
And i found the solution. There was some issue in Postman so this error solved and now i am getting the result in api calling.